# Redis Graph: Merge on existing nodes

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

Imagine that two nodes, `(:USER {name: "John"})` and `(:AGE {name: "28"})`, exist. Now, the following query is ok with Neo4j

```
MATCH (u:USER {name: "John"})
MATCH (a:AGE {name: "28"})
MERGE (u)-[:IS]->(a)
```

and creates the `IS` relationship between the two nodes. When the same query is run on Redis Graph, I get the following error:
`Syntax error at offset 22 near 'MERGE'`. Does anyone know how to run the same query on Redis Graph?

I should add that `CREATE` does not work instead of `MERGE` since it will create a duplicate of an (possibly) already existing edge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Currently, MERGE only functions as a standalone clause so it cannot be combined with other directives such as MATCH or RETURN.

Reference: [Merge command](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/commands/#merge), [GitHub issue](https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph/issues/181)

You can do something like this (but it will create the whole pattern instead):

```
MERGE (u:USER {name: "John"})-[:IS]->(a:AGE {name: "28"})
```

So I think the only option for now is to perform two separate commands:

```
MATCH (u:USER {name: "John"})-[r:IS]->(a:AGE {name: "28"})
RETURN count(r)
```

If this transaction return empty result then you need to create the relationship:

```
MATCH (u:USER {name: "John"})
MATCH (a:AGE {name: "28"})
CREATE (u)-[:IS]->(a)
```

***Edit***:
After 20-06-2020, this answer is not relevant since they are now support such queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rawhi. Yeah, right now I do separate commands as well and it works ok. However, I just find a duplicate of my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680683/node-reuse-instead-of-creating-new-ones, who's also running separate commands but in some MULTI query thingy.